# why I get this /bin/sh: 1: ^Mno: not found error

Tags: linux, logs, cron

I have typed `for user in $(cut -f1 -d: /etc/passwd); do crontab -u $user -l; done`
And that say

```
no crontab for root
no crontab for daemon
...
no crontab for apache2
```

and i got very often You have new mail in /var/mail/root message

when i read there are all the same

```
From root@lxc2014.localdomain  Wed Aug  2 15:40:02 2017
Return-Path: <root@lxc2014.localdomain>
X-Original-To: root
Delivered-To: root@lxc2014.localdomain
Received: by lxc2014.localdomain (Postfix, from userid 0)
        id 03E571D666; Wed,  2 Aug 2017 15:40:02 +0000 (UTC)
From: root@lxc2014.localdomain (Cron Daemon)
To: root@lxc2014.localdomain
Subject: Cron <root@lxc2014> /dev/.x;^Mno crontab for root
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=US-ASCII
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/root>
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=root>
Message-Id: <20170802154002.03E571D666@lxc2014.localdomain>
Date: Wed,  2 Aug 2017 15:40:02 +0000 (UTC)

/bin/sh: 1: ^Mno: not found
```

I know that ^M is \r brut why cron search this file...

Comment: There are a few system crontabs in addition to per-user crontabs. Does `grep "no crontab" /etc/crontab /etc/cron*/* | cat -vet` show anything?

Comment: ```grep "no crontab" /etc/crontab /etc/cron*/* | cat -vet``` show nothing

Comment: i've php5 in cron.d and apache2  apt  aptitude  bsdmainutils  dpkg  logrotate  man-db  mlocate  passwd
 in cron.daily

Comment: Can you try `grep -F -r /dev/.x /etc /var/spool/cron | cat -vet` ? I've never seen `/dev/.x` before. It may be a legitimate executable used to maintain `/dev`, or it may be suspicious.

Comment: /var/spool/cron/crontabs/root:* * * * * /dev/.x;^Mno crontab for root$

Comment: the content of this file :# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall.\n
# (- installed on Thu Jul 20 20:50:12 2017)\n
# (Cron version -- $Id: crontab.c,v 2.13 1994/01/17 03:20:37 vixie Exp $)\n
* * * * * /dev/.x;^Mno crontab for root

Comment: It's beginning to look like someone intentionally tried to hide the crontab from being viewed with `crontab -u root -l`. The `^M` there will cause the first part of the line to be overwritten with the string `no crontab for root`. Ask other people who have admin access to your system whether they added this cron entry on July 20. If nobody did, then ask a security/forensics person to take a look.

Comment: I tried `ls /dev -a` and I don't see .x file so I don't think someone want to hide something how I can check. I tried `crontab -u root -l` and have `no crontab for root`. I will contact the other admin.

Comment: Try `ls -a /dev` (ls wants options to precede names). If you run `crontab -u root -l | cat -vet` it will show invisible characters.

Comment: `-ls -a /dev` show nothing more than `-ls /dev -a`. I've asked other admin and they didn't add this cron job. I've found temporary solution: comment this job by adding `# ` but i want to find real solution. So `crontab -u root -l | cat -vet` produce this line `# * * * * * /dev/.x;^Mno crontab for root$`

Comment: Does the command `file /dev/.x` show anything?

Comment: /dev/.x: cannot open `/dev/.x' (No such file or directory)

Comment: Looks like the file isn't there any more. The mail from cron was complaining about the second command on that line, `^Mno`, implying that the first command `/dev/.x` at one point could be successfully executed.

Comment: So i can erase this job of the cron list?

Comment: Sure. Use `crontab -u root -r`. That crontab entry was either a typo or malicious software (or both).

Comment: thanks my problem is fixed put your comment in answer for I can mark as solved ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get mail like

```
From: root@lxc2014.localdomain (Cron Daemon)
To: root@lxc2014.localdomain
Subject: Cron <root@lxc2014> /dev/.x;^Mno crontab for root
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=root>

/bin/sh: 1: ^Mno: not found
```

and you can't tell which crontab contains the offending command, you can grep for pieces of command in the standard places:

```
grep -r "no crontab" /etc/cron* /var/spool/cron | cat -vet
```

The `cat -vet` will show any embedded control characters that would otherwise be invisible or result in cursor motion.

In your case, you found the command at

```
/var/spool/cron/crontabs/root:* * * * * /dev/.x;^Mno crontab for root$
```

and the file contains this (line breaks added for readability):

```
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE - edit the master and reinstall.\n
# (- installed on Thu Jul 20 20:50:12 2017)\n
# (Cron version -- $Id: crontab.c,v 2.13 1994/01/17 03:20:37 vixie Exp $)\n
* * * * * /dev/.x;^Mno crontab for root
```

Because of the embedded <kbd>Ctrl+M</kbd> character, running `crontab -u root -l` appears to show only `no crontab for root`.  **This looks like someone is trying to hide the crontab entry. I suggest that someone familiar with security and forensics take a look at your system to determine whether it's been compromised.**

You can remove this crontab with `crontab -u root -r`.

You mentioned that `/dev/.x` doesn't exist, and that that string doesn't appear in any file under `/etc`, but please keep monitoring your system to see whether these files reappear. That would be a strong indicator that your system is still compromised.

If possible, please install all security patches offered by your distribution.

Comment: Related: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/39231/how-do-i-deal-with-a-compromised-server

Comment: this command `crontab -u root -r` work well but after some reboot this entry come back...

Comment: Looks like it's malware, then. Reinstall your system and make sure you're fully patched and change all your access passwords. See the link provided by @Kusalananda

Comment: Ok i'll try to convince other admin.